# What is the mean of symbol(?) in that link?

Tags: html, css

`

```
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codecovers.eu/assets/css/modules/materialadmin/css/theme-default/materialadmin.css?1422823243">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codecovers.eu/assets/css/modules/materialadmin/css/theme-default/font-awesome.min.css?1422823239">`
```

In that img, I saw "?" after link css
Ex: bootstrap.css?1422823..

What's that mean ?

Comment: Please copy the text into your post. Do not use pictures to show text. Thanks.

Comment: It is used to clear cache.

Comment: Please, add your code instead of image.

Comment: @alirezasafian It is not used to clear cache. It might be used to get around the cache, but that's not the same

Comment: @MrLister Do you mean we close the question wrongly?

Comment: @alirezasafian No, I did not. I just said you're not clearing the cache when you put a random number behind the url.

Comment: @MrLister It is used to clear browser cache. Is it correct?

Comment: @alirezasafian Like I said, no. You are not clearing the cache. If you have loaded three versions of the url (with three different random numbers) into your browser, then there will be three copies of the stylesheet in the cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98786/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-mr-lister).

Comment: @MrLister It's true. So, what you call that action?